# Source for Specific Models of Birds' Habitat Suitability

Tags: ornithology, database, research-tools, habitat

This [source](https://www.fws.gov/r5gomp/gom/habitatstudy/metadata/GOM_GIS_Data_Table.htm) gives a very detailed analysis of what habitats are best suited for many different species. However, this is a government funded project and, to the best of my knowledge, not published in a peer-reviewed paper. In addition, this project has officially been depreciated for 18 years.

There are 2 features of this project that are very attractive to my own project. First, each habitat is ranked as a value between 0 and 1. Second, it ranks 31 habitats, each with very precise differences (e.g. a conifer palustrine forest habitat is ranked separately from a deciduous palustrine forest). Compare this to other sources, such as the IUCN Red List which only says 'Yes' or 'No' to whether a species has been observed in a habitat and only tracks 18 habitats that are very broad groups (e.g. all forests are ranked together).

Can anyone direct me to a more modern and/or peer-reviewed source that has one or both of these benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google reveals several databases of bird habitats, which appear to be at least somewhat more recent.

I believe that the one closest to what you describe is [here](http://datazone.birdlife.org/species/spchabalt) (there may not be a single publication but they do have a lot of associated publications on their site). But this [climate change geospatial database](https://www.nrs.fs.fed.us/atlas/bird/) (with a newer version [here](https://www.fs.fed.us/nrs/atlas/bird/)) and [this more local database](https://catalog.data.gov/harvest/object/4e87fe2a-09c3-42df-a2c8-99cc4def7373/html) may also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I think I missed those when searching because I always included terms like "dataset" or "database".